# Facebook API, Using FB Connect on email address

Tags: asp.net, facebook

ASP.Net C# and FaceBook Connect.

I'm using Facebook connect on my site.  If a new user connects through FB i create an account for them and all is fine.  What i would also like to do is check to see if they already have a registered account.

So if someone connects that has not logged in but has an account i would like to be able to locate the account in my application a link it.  I hoping this could be done via the email address?

Any ideas

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  You need **[Connect.registerUsers](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect.registerUsers)**:

> This method is used to create an
>   association between an existing user
>   account on your site and that user's
>   Facebook account, provided the user
>   has not connected accounts before.
>
> This method takes an array of account
>   data, including a required email_hash
>   and optional account data. For each
>   connected account, if the user exists,
>   the information is added to the set of
>   the user's connected accounts. If the
>   user has already authorized the site,
>   the connected account is added in the
>   confirmed state. If the user has not
>   yet authorized the site, the connected
>   account is added in the pending state.
>
> If the user deactivates their external
>   user account, then call
>   connect.unregisterUsers. To get the
>   number of friends a user has in the
>   pending state, use
>   connect.getUnconnectedFriendsCount.

If that doesn't resolve your question, this question is not a duplicate of yours, but the answers might give you a way forward:

- [How do we register users — Facebook Connect users logging in the first time — when we cannot get an email address from facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220144/how-do-we-register-users-facebook-connect-users-logging-in-the-first-time-w)